# Can run a php application with Nginx manually when Laravel Valet is installed?

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx, valet

i have **valet** installed and configured on my system.and all i do is go to my browser and do folder-name.test and the project runs.
now,can i run a PHP application which is outside of valet folder with `nginx` manually?

Comment: Seeing you current nginx config can be helpful to answer this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.